# Touchpad failure after upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, touchpad

I have just bought an HP laptop pre-loaded with ubuntu. I was expecting it to be 14.04 but it was not and this was available as a downloadable upgrade.

Suffice to say the upgrade crashed my touchpad and it no longer works. I have tried several terminal based patches but this does not work either.

I can not log in to the root system to enable permissions for editing the grub file and now the I can not type in the password for the system in the terminal either.

**Has anyone got a reliable and simple patch that will get the touchpad working again?**

Comment: May I ask what distribution you had installed prior to upgrading to 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrades have been known to cause issues, and the officially supported upgrades are LTS to LTS (12.04 - 14.04)

The quickest way to solve your type of issue in my experience is to

1. Boot a live cd of 14.04 and test whether your touchpad works in the live environment (Thus confirming this is a software issue, not a hardware issue)
2. Do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04; Because you bought it preinstalled, presumably from someone else; there is a chance we are not dealing with a clean version of ubuntu.

**Good luck, and welcome to the community!**